# Where can i publish a Raspberry pi 2 - Ros indigo ISO image?

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, image, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys and thanks for Ros :)

I spend several days installing Ros Indigo desktop on my new Raspberry pi 2. My main error i think was to start with the Noob OS thinking it was base on Debian Wheezy.

After a lot of try and fail, i started from scratch using Raspbian Debian Wheezy. It work perfectly but still need 1 day to install.

I would like to share this image with the community, but I'm not sure where i should publish the link.
By google i only find some blog, and it doesn't seems to have public image of ROS indigo desktop for raspberry pi 2.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1350541/raspberry2ROSindigo.7z.torrent
The image is compressed to ~1,4GO and take 16Go uncompressed.

---

Follow up question ( @Tontome ):

I tried to flash it on a 16GB flash card with this command : 
sudo dd bs=4M if=raspberry2ROSindigo of=/dev/sdc

But I got the error :
dd: error writing ‘/dev/sdc’: No space left on device 
3770+0 records in 
3769+0 records out 
15811477504 bytes (16 GB) copied, 1704.68 s, 9.3 MB/s

What command do you use to flash it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213490/where-can-i-publish-a-raspberry-pi-2---ros-indigo-iso-image?/) by [Amrac](https://answers.ros.org/users/23079/amrac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-07-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amrac](https://answers.ros.org/users/23079/amrac/) on 2015-09-02**:
Hi,
I use Win32diskmanager, you can get it here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should talk to the [ROS users mailing list](http://lists.ros.org/mailman/listinfo/ros-users).

Follow up answer:

The issue here might be that the image is slightly larger than your card. Mount the drive image and shrink the partition sizes, then grow them to fill the card when you have copied the files (ROS is a lot of things, but it is not 16 GB...). Let me know if you need help with that.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2015-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rossi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4597/rossi/) on 2015-10-20**:
Hello allenh1,
Is it possible to get the Image? I try the torrent file, but there are no Peers.

**Comment by [Amrac](https://answers.ros.org/users/23079/amrac/) on 2015-10-20**:
My torrent server is down, i will re-up it tonight in 3 or 4 Hours

**Comment by [Amrac](https://answers.ros.org/users/23079/amrac/) on 2015-10-20**:
Got a scaleway.com server, im uploading the torrent back :)

**Comment by [rossi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4597/rossi/) on 2015-10-20**:
Big thanks to you, Amrac! You saved me (and others) a lot of work.